# If Else block trouble

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am have trouble with this If ElseIf block and I cannot figure out where the error is.

The message I get is "Else without if".

I am very new to using if elseif any help or guidance would be appreciated.

Line of Error:

```
ElseIf booSM = True And _
       booInv = True And _
       booHOP = False _
       Then strTo = Me.txtServiceManager.Column(1) & ";" & Me.txtInvestigator.Column(1)
```

Full code:

```
Dim txtScan As String
Dim strTo As String
Dim booSM As Boolean
Dim booInv As Boolean
Dim booHOP As Boolean

Me.Refresh
txtScan = Me.txtScanLocation
booSM = booComDocSMSent
booInv = booComDocInvSent
booHOP = booComDocHOPSent

If booSM = True And _
   booInv = True And _
   booHOP = True _
   Then strTo = Me.txtServiceManager.Column(1) & ";" & Me.txtInvestigator.Column(1) & ";" &  Me.txtHop.Column(1)
ElseIf booSM = True And _
       booInv = True And _
       booHOP = False _
       Then strTo = Me.txtServiceManager.Column(1) & ";" & Me.txtInvestigator.Column(1)
ElseIf booSM = True And _
       booInv = False And _
       booHOP = True _
       Then strTo = Me.txtServiceManager.Column(1) & ";" & Me.txtHop.Column(1)
ElseIf booSM = False And _
       booInv = True And _
       booHOP = True _
       Then strTo = Me.txtInvestigator.Column(1) & ";" & Me.txtHop.Column(1)
ElseIf booSM = True And _
       booInv = False And _
       booHOP = False _
       Then strTo = Me.txtServiceManager.Column(1)
ElseIf booSM = False And _
       booInv = True And _
       booHOP = False _
       Then strTo = Me.txtInvestigator.Column(1)
ElseIf booSM = False And _
       booInv = False And _
       booHOP = True _
       Then strTo = Me.txtHop.Column(1)
End If
```

Comment: Does the error message tell you which line the error is on?

Comment: added line where it appears.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look into the following logic of `If statement` code sections:

```
Sub Logic()
'Attempt 1st
    If a = 1 And _
        b = 1 _
        Then C = 1 'end of if statement

'Attempt 2nd
    If a = 1 And _
        b = 1 _
        Then _
        C = 1 'end of if statement

'Attempt 3rd
    If a = 1 And _
        b = 1 _
        Then
        C = 1 'and continuation below
    ElseIf a = 1 And _
        b = 1 _
        Then
        'something here
    End If
End Sub
```

There are three different logic of writing `if conditions check`. in your situation you either missed some `_ underline marks` or you should move some lines into next line (the code after `Then` key words).

Comment: Thank you that did work but why does it work after the line has been moved below the Then statement?

Comment: These are just syntax rules for `if statements` we all need to stick to. For more information try to check [this MSDN information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/752y8abs.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I don't have VBA to hand, but it looks like its a problem with your line endings

The format

```
if condition then
  statement
elesif conditon
  statement
end if
```

you are using line continuation ( _ ) and your format looks like

```
if condition then statement
elseif condition then statement
endif
```

so

```
If booSM = True And booInv = True And booHOP = True Then 
   strTo = Me.txtServiceManager.Column(1) & ";" & Me.txtInvestigator.Column(1) & ";" &  Me.txtHop.Column(1)
ElseIf booSM = True And booInv = True And booHOP = False Then 
  strTo = Me.txtServiceManager.Column(1) & ";" & Me.txtInvestigator.Column(1)
End If
```

might work better for you
or if you want to keep some multi line formatting

```
If booSM = True And _
   booInv = True And _
   booHOP = True Then 
       strTo = Me.txtServiceManager.Column(1) & ";" & Me.txtInvestigator.Column(1) & ";" &  Me.txtHop.Column(1)
ElseIf booSM = True And _
       booInv = True And _
       booHOP = False _
Then 
      strTo = Me.txtServiceManager.Column(1) & ";" & Me.txtInvestigator.Column(1)
End If
```